# Grouping 3D coordinates within a certain distance of any other "group member"

Tags: java, algorithm, coordinates

I'm looking for an efficient way (or existing library/tool) to group 3D coordinates that are within a given distance from another "group member" coordinate. So if 5 coordinates are within 2m of at least 1 member of that group, they'll be lumped into a single group.

Comparing the distance from every coordinate to every other coordinate would be awful performance. Some possible solutions require knowing how many groups you'll have ahead of time, which I do not. Some solutions in python rely on large math libraries I won't have in java and would prefer not to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest efficient approach here would be a sweep and prune algorithm to identify the close-enough pairs, and a union-find structure to use those edges to produce the groups. You should be able to find existing code for both halves pretty easily.

Comment: How about DBSCAN? I see apache has a basic implementation, would that work or would your suggestion likely be more efficient/easier to adapt?